# Not able to run Perl script after installing Active Perl

Tags: perl

After installing ActivePerl 5.8.7, I am trying to run a perl script but it says perl is not recognized as internal or external command. What should I do in order to run my script? Are there any things we should do after installing Active Perl. I am using a Windows 7 system

Comment: Have you added perl the `bin` folder of the installed perll to your Path?

Comment: If you have used the ActivePerl installer, all should be well. You could possibly run the script by providing the full path to the Perl executable, e.g. `c:\Perl\bin\perl.exe script.pl` On a more personal note, I gave up on ActivePerl long ago in favour of Strawberry Perl. Much less fuss, and I can use the modules I want, not just the ones ActivePerl has precompiled.

Comment: Why using such an old version (June 2005)?